# What does "the strays" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

In one of Friends' episodes Joey went to a beauty salon to get his eyebrows waxed. The salon professional said the following sentence to Joey:

> We'll get to the wax in a minute. First, I want to tweeze some of the
> strays. OK?

What does "the strays" mean here?

Comment: https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0913.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is that Joey is getting his eyebrows [waxed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxing) Before the technician waxes (removes the hair from) the main part of his eyebrows, she notices some hairs which are not part of the main portion of eyebrow hair. She calls these "stray" hairs and says she will *tweeze* them, which means "to remove with [tweezers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweezers)."

In this context, for a hair to be "stray" means "it is away from where it should be."

Answer (score 2):

Joey was having wax treatment to remove hair from his eyebrow region. Some stray hairs must have stayed behind after the wax was pulled off, and these were removed with an instrument called 'tweezers'. The verb 'tweeze' is derived from that. Here is *a pair of tweezers*:

[image]

> Stray
>
> an isolated or random occurrence, specimen, etc, that is out of place
> or outside the usual pattern

[Stray (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stray)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - the eyebrow area is part of the body, isn't it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: Aaah, I would have kept the image, a painting is worth a 1000 words etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - agreed.